# Code command: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput-config.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glibc

A few days ago I dualbooted my laptop. I can't use the code command because I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput-config.so' from /etc/ld.so.preload cannot be preloaded (failed to map segment from shared object): ignored.
/snap/code/137/usr/share/code/bin/../code: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput-config.so)
```

I have searched hours for a fix but I can't find anything. Im a complete linux beginner so I don't know what can cause this issue. Does anyone have an idea how I could possibly fix the preload problem?

I made sure I installed every package I think I need.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using sudo vim on the /etc/ld.so.preload file and deleting the line /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libinput-config.so.